# Why do I get ArrayIndexOutOfBounds when I use -1 to exit from loop?

Tags: java

I'm making a cards and deck class. I've made it to the point where it asks user to input number from 1-52 which will display a card, and a -1 to exit from the loop. Once the loop ends it'll display all 52 cards. Eventually, I'd like for my program to reach the point where the user inputs how many cards they'd like to be dealt, and the program will deal the hand. Before I get there I keep getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error after I input -1. Here's my code,

My cards class (kept the snippet short):

```
public class Cards
    {
        private Face face;
        private Suit suit;

        public Cards ()
        {
            face = Face.ACE;
            suit = Suit.SPADES;
        }

        public Cards (int n)
        {

            face = Face.values() [n % 13];
            suit = Suit.values() [n % 4];
        }
    }
```

My driver:

```
public class driver
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);        //For int
        Scanner kb2 = new Scanner(System.in);       //For strings
        int iNum=0;             //holds users input for non-negative number
        String strDeck;         //variable to catch showDeck

        do
        {
            System.out.println ("Enter a number between 1-52, enter -1 to stop.");

            iNum = kb.nextInt();
            if (iNum <= -1)
            {
                strDeck = showDeck();
            }
            Cards userCard = new Cards(iNum);
            System.out.println ("Your card is " + userCard.toString());
        }

        while (iNum >= -1);
        {
            System.out.println("Press ENTER to continue ");
            kb2.nextLine();
        }
```

Sorry for the spacing problem, specifically the error I get is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at cards.Cards.<init>(Cards.java:44)
at cards.driver.main(driver.java:28)
```

Comment: Just like to also note that your do-while loop condition runs on the premise that it keeps running when it is more than or equal to -1, which in this case should be >-1, because at exactly -1 you don't want the condition to run anymore. As for if(iNum<= -1) that would mean a value less than -1 showsDeck() too. Is that intended?

Comment: Yeah, I meant for it to be `iNum > -1`, I've haven't totally grasped the logic behind `do-while` loops as of yet.

Comment: good luck then, I've been there, and been a teaching assistant for a Java class so I can understand. The debugger for stepping through code is very useful, as Jason said, here's a nice tutorial for your reference: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, as your code says, when the user enters -1, it goes on to do `new Card(iNum)`, which is `new Card(-1)` (just after that `if` statement).

Perhaps you meant to put that bit in an `else` statement, or you could also `break` out of the loop after the `showDeck()` call.

---

By the way, mind your line breaks. The way your code is formatted now may be somewhat confusing. You have:

```
do {
   ...
}

while (iNum >= 1);
{
   ...
}
```

But that `while` is part of the `do` loop, not part of the `{ ... }` scope that follows it (note where the semicolon is). The formatting is somewhat misleading and can easily lead to mistakes. You may wish to format like this instead:

```
do {
   ...
} while (iNum >= 1);

{
   ...
}
```

Although this all appears to be a bit of a typo anyways, as I suspect you meant to apply that `while` condition to the "Press ENTER to continue" bit also/instead.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I threw in an `else` after the `if` statement, and fixed the `while` statement to `iNum >  -1`

Comment: @ph0bolus You should familiarize yourself with a debugger, e.g. the one that comes with Eclipse or NetBeans. Then you can step through your code one line at a time to see exactly what's happening.

Comment: I am currently using Eclipse, it's a big step up from notepad ++ which they had us using in the beginning of the semester. It's  definitely helpful for going through and fixing syntax errors, it's the logical errors where I struggle at times.